# clear statement about the relation between curvature and rotating vectors along a loop

Tags: geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature

in my research, I need to understand the relation between the formal definition of Riemann curvature tensor ($R_{jkl}^i$)and the ``vector rotation" approach: parallel transport a vector along a loop, then define the curvature tensor by
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{{\hat{\xi^k}(\epsilon)}-\xi^k}{\epsilon^2}=-R_{lij}^k \xi^l
$$
where $\hat{\xi}$ is the vector after rotation, along a square with edge length $\epsilon$.

(This formula is given in an exercise of Novikov et al. book "Modern Geometry")

I referred to Wiki, but not quite understand yet...

Is there any detailed material on such issue, or how to establish such relation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think i saw something about this on spivak treatise of differential geometry vol 2  "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry".

Comment: Thank you! Let me check that.